# vpn daemon altering and updating resolv.conf each time i modify it

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, vpn, resolv.conf

I'm running a 3rd party vpn daemon that changes resolv.conf on init and checks for changes continuously.

I installed my own local dns cache that gets properly inside resolv.conf but the vpn daemon puts its resolvers before that and I'm getting huge timeouts.

Any idea on how could I use another config file to specify I want to resolve my own stuff or at least reducing the standard dns timeout(5 secs) without touching resolv.conf

Answer (score 3):

I'd be invoking the awesome power of `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` to make the file immutable, or else hunting down the author of the VPN client and beating them around the head with a clue-by-four.

Comment: Tell it who's boss. You shouldn't need to adapt around it.

Comment: Looks like a good one, but I do need it to modify it to add vpns own dns to work, just after my own local dns, not before.

Comment: Add the VPN's DNS servers yourself where you want them, then `chattr` it.